# Is it possible to have race conditions at App Engine while updating ListProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, concurrency

Let's say I have a model `User` with property `bands` of type `StringListProperty`. In a request handler, I'm extending/appending to `bands` list and also I'm creating a lot of tasks for `taskqueue`, whose handlers will also append to the `bands` list. Is it possible to have race conditions?

Comment: Are you saving `User` to datastore and then reading it in taskqueue?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You'll need to read/modify/write the entity within a transaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Tasks within Transaction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview#Tasks_within_Transactions) to make sure your tasks are only enqueued if the corresponding Datastore transaction has been committed successfully.

Just add `transactional=True` keyword arg when adding tasks within a transaction:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/my/worker', transactional=True)
```